# Wordpress scroll animation to id

Tags: wordpress, scroll

i'm trying to get my wordpress site to do the animate scroll to id, by using the scroll to id by malihu

I can't get it to work. When i click the link it just jump down to the page.
it´s a one page site..

```
<div class="wrapper">

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#et" rel='m_PageScroll2id'>Et</a></li>
        <li><a href="#to" rel='m_PageScroll2id'>To</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tre" rel='m_PageScroll2id'>Tre</a></li>
        <li><a href="#fire" rel='m_PageScroll2id'>Fire</a></li> 
    </ul>
</nav>




<div class="side" id="et">
    <h1 id="section-1">Et</h1>
</div>

<div class="side" id="to">
    <h1 id="section-2">to</h1>
</div>

<div class="side" id="tre">
    <h1 id="section-3">tre</h1>
</div>

<div class="side" id="fire">
    <h1 id="section-4">fire</h1>
    <h2 id="scrollto">Heading 2</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with an alternate method, take a look at this demo http://codepen.io/mattsince87/pen/exByn.